# Call to undefined function pspell_new() on widows & php 8

Tags: php, laravel, aspell

I have some problem with my laravel application, this application using pspell (Aspell) for spell check correction. When i run this app on OSX that app running without error, but when i run this app on windows with same settings (php 8) and Aspell for windows the application show errors "Call to undefined function pspell_new()".

i have tried install Aspell for windows but its not work.

Comment: Have you followed the specific instructions for Windows users under https://www.php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php ?

Comment: i've copy C:\Program Files\Aspell\bin to windows environment variable (system PATH) but its doesnt work